# Angular JS Script Application always return True with Wcf Service

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf

I am consuming Wcf REST Service into Angular JS Application. I am creating userlogin site based on username and password . My Wcf Service got boolean method its return true or false. But the problem is what ever username information i provide into input filed my Script file code always returns true .

Here is my Interface ..

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "/AuthenticateUser")]
        bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin );
```

Here is implementation of the Interface ..

```
 public bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin)
        {

            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                string encryptedpassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(userLogin.Password, "SHA1");
                SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userLogin.Username);
                SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedpassword);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int RetryAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["RetryAttempts"]);
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["AccountLocked"]))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (RetryAttempts > 0)
                    {
                        int AttemptsLeft = (4 - RetryAttempts);
                        return true;

                    }

                    else if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Authenticated"]))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }


                }
                return true;


            }
            }
```

Here is my Script file code ..

```
///// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  



var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])

    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;

        //1 Mean New Entry  

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;
            $scope.Username = "";
            $scope.Password = "";

        }
        $scope.login = function () {
            var User = {
                Username: $scope.Username,
                Password: $scope.Password,
            };
            myService.AuthenticateUser(User).then(function (pl) {
                console.log(pl.data)
                if (pl.data) {
                    $scope.msg = "Password or username is correct !"
                }
                else {
                    $scope.msg = "Password Incorrect !";
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                }
                }, function (err) {
                $scope.msg = "Password or username is Incorrect !";
                console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
            });
        };



    }]);



app.service("myService", function ($http) {



    this.AuthenticateUser = function (User) {
        return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/AuthenticateUser", JSON.stringify(User));
    }
})
```

Here is the out put when i run the application..

[image: Click here to see the result]

Please provide your valueable feedback to correct this error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are always returning true from the method, just remove the last line, introduce a variable and assign the result to that variable and return it,

```
public bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        var result = false;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string encryptedpassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(userLogin.Password, "SHA1");
        SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userLogin.Username);
        SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedpassword);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            int RetryAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["RetryAttempts"]);
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["AccountLocked"]))
            {
                result = false;
            }
            else if (RetryAttempts > 0)
            {
                int AttemptsLeft = (4 - RetryAttempts);
                result = true;

            }

            else if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Authenticated"]))
            {
                result = true;
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there everything ok .in script file ??

Comment: @Mohammad did you try as mentioned

Comment: still return true and always displaying this message ... $scope.msg = "Password or username is correct !"

Comment: it cannot be, did you restart the wcf service

Comment: Yes i did it but why still same result